# Joomla 2.5 - JUser does not return user group names

Tags: joomla

I would like to get the user groups of a user. I use the following code:

```
$CurrentUser =& JFactory::getUser();
print_r($CurrentUser->groups);
```

Now, in version 1.5 of Joomla, it prints out this array:

Array ( [Registered] => 2 [Author] => 3 [RBGS_RBS_U15_Trainer] => 1063 )

and in v2.5 i get this one:

Array ( [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [1063] => 1063 )

So is there a possibility in v2.5 to get the names of the user groups?

Thanks in advance,

enne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is to change one line of code. Browse to libraries/joomla/database/table/user.php.
There, change the line

```
$this->groups = $this->_db->loadAssocList('id', 'id');
```

to

```
$this->groups = $this->_db->loadAssocList('title', 'id');
```

and it should work.

Comment: Well, yes. But this does not help on the long run. The next time you update / upgrade this change may be overridden. Possible workarounds are ACL or direct query in the database.